# Excel 2016 - if value of any cell in column A of sheet 1 = A1 of sheet 2 then show value of sheet 1, column D of that row in A2 of sheet 2

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I would like to have a cell reference another with an IF statement like this:

IF the value of any Cell in Column A of Sheet 1 is 100 then this cell (Sheet 2, cell A2 for example) should be the value of Column D for the row where the value of the Cell in Column A is 100. And also Column D for that Row may change whereas it's Column A value for that same Row may stay the same.

This means i want to look for changes in Column A. Sometimes 100 might be Row 2, but sometimes it might be Row 302. Also, if Sheet 1, Column A, Value=100 stays in the same Row, but its Column D value changes, I'd want Sheet 2, Cell A2 to reflect that change in Column D for the Row where Value=100. And I want Sheet 2, Cell A2 to reflect whatever Column D is for the row where Column A equals 100.

VLOOKUP only searches column A when properly sorted, but i'd like to be able to search any unsorted column for the matching value.

Comment: A `VLOOKUP` or `INDEX/MATCH` *may* do the job., It would be a lot easier to follow your explanation with sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This finds the first instance of 100 in column A and returns the value from column D of the same row.

```
=INDIRECT("D"&MATCH(100,A:A,0))
```

or referencing another sheet:

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet1!D"&MATCH(100,Sheet1!A:A,0))
```

Comment: that looks to be the correct logic. will try and upvote if it works. but what would i add to reference another sheet?